# promesas encadenadas

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Hola estoy haciendo un `script` en donde lo debo hace a través de promesas, solo soporta promesas la versión de `Nodejs` instalada.

**Tengo que utilizar en las distintas promesas los resultados de las anteriores**.
Acá mi código para algo de ayuda:

```
  ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response =>{

        return response;

    }).then(response2=>{
     //proceso2
       return ListaconCondicionProceso(response2)


    }).then(response3=>{
    //proceso3

         return FiltrarPagoProceso()

    }).then (response4=>{

//aqui necesito llamar una funcion (promesa) que compare los resultados de los proceso1, proceso2 y proceso3

 })
```

Cada uno de los procesos son promesas...no se si me entienden, discúlpenme lo errores estoy comenzando, gracias de antemano...

Comment: Hola. Si una respuesta no sirve, la solución no es intentar editarla y cambiarla por basura. Puedes comentar la respuesta indicando que no solucionó tu problema y el resultado de intentar usarla. Puedes incluso votar la respuesta positiva o negativamente. Pero definitivamente, no vandalices los contenidos sólo porque no te sirven.

Comment: Gracias y disculpa

Comment: Un poco para salir de la rutina y reirnos, el título de tu pregunta se me antoja a título de novela romántica, decidí hacer algo al respecto. He [aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETTQI.jpg) el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Jajajajajajjaj muy buena!

Comment: jajajajajaj gracias igual jajajajajaj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existen 2 opciones, la primera es llevar un registro del resultado de tus promises para al final poder usar este registro, la segunda es usar `Promise.all`:

```js
ListarUsuariosMaxDate = new Promise((res, rej) =>{
  res('Luis, Juan, Daniel');
});

function ListaconCondicionProceso(){
   return 'otro valor';
}

function FiltrarPagoProceso(){
   return '240.000';
}

ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response =>{

   return [response];

}).then(response2=>{

   //proceso2
   response2.push(ListaconCondicionProceso(response2))
   return response2;


}).then(response3=>{

   //proceso3
   response3.push(FiltrarPagoProceso());
   return response3;

}).then (response4=>{

//aqui necesito llamar una funcion (promesa) que compare los resultados de los proceso1, proceso2 y proceso3

   //Resultado de los procesos almacenados
   console.log(...response4);

})
```

Si, se que se ve horrible, pero es para poder llevar un registro de tus procesos, de lo contrario no hay forma de volver atras a una promise y que te devuelva el resultado de tus procesos sin nombrarlos.

Otra forma que hay es usando `Promise.all` pero para poder usar `Promise.all` requeriras tener un iterable de promises, es decir, un array de promises, así que miremos la forma con `Promise.all`:

```js
const processList = [];

ListarUsuariosMaxDate = new Promise((res, rej) =>{
  res('Luis, Juan, Daniel');
});

function ListaconCondicionProceso(){
   return 'otro valor';
}

function FiltrarPagoProceso(){
   return '240.000';
}

ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response =>{

   processList.push(new Promise((res, rej) => res(response)));
   return response;

}).then(response2=>{

   //proceso2
   processList.push(new Promise((res, rej) => res(ListaconCondicionProceso(response2))));
   return ListaconCondicionProceso(response2);


}).then(response3=>{

   //proceso3
   processList.push(new Promise((res, rej) => res(FiltrarPagoProceso())));
   return FiltrarPagoProceso();

}).then (response4=>{

//aqui necesito llamar una funcion (promesa) que compare los resultados de los proceso1, proceso2 y proceso3

   Promise.all(processList).then(responses =>{
       //Resultado de los procesos almacenados
       
       console.log(responses);
   });

})
```

Se ve un poco el feo el código... pero en resumen `Promise.all` itera y va ejecutando las promises en el orden en que las pusiste, y cuando este este preparado nos devuelve una `promise` que se resuelve cuando todas tus promises han sido resueltas o un error cuando por lo menos una de ellas ha fallado (ha entrado al catch).

Comment: Gracias @Riven se ven tu experiencia en tema, gracias amig@...simpre prest@ a brindar tus conocimientos a los que nos estamos iniciando en el tema...Ojala hayan mas como tu...