# Uso de Promises encadenadas

Tags: javascript, promesas, callback

Estoy empezando con Promises y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
let datos = ["Jorge Balsamo","@SoyDalto","Curso de Javascript"];

function validarNombre(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(datos[0]!="Jorge Balsamo") reject("El nombre indicado no es el correcto");
        else resolve("El nombre es correcto");
    })
}

function validarInstagram(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(datos[1].includes("@") && datos[1]!=undefined) resolve("Instagram validado correctamente");
        else reject("El IG es invalido o es undefined");
    })
}

function validarCurso(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(datos[2]!="Curso de Javascript") reject("El curso indicado no es el correcto");
        else resolve("El nombre del curso es correcto");
    })
}
```

Mi intencion era encadenar Promesas para poder capturar los errores con un solo catch pero no pude y tuve que hacerlos uno por uno

```
validarNombre().then(validarInstagram().catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
})).then(validarCurso().catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
}))
```

Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es encadenar las Promesas para al final agregar un catch que me capture y muestre en consola los errores de cualquiera de las 3 funciones. Esa es supuestamente la ventaja de usar promises contra solo usar callbacks, pero no puedo implementar el encadenamiento correctamente (estoy empezando sorry).

Comment: Describe por favor por qué dices que no funciona. ¿Qué esperas cómo resultado? Yo acabo de [encadenar las tres promesas](https://pastebin.com/aADxxD5Q) y funciona perfectamente. Si hay un error en alguna de las tres salta directamente al catch. Edita tu pregunta y aclara lo que buscas y que es lo que estas obteniendo. Tal y como está se hace dificil ayudarte ya que pones lo que "tuviste que hacer", pero no lo que hiciste.

Comment: necesito saber como se encadenan eso es lo que busco. Me rompi el coco para encadenarlas y no me sale. Lo mas cercano es lo que ves ahi: no tengo un catch sino 2. Lo que entendi sobre las promises es que todos los errores se podian capturar en un catch al final y no estiy logrando eso

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [promesas encadenadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352472/promesas-encadenadas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### En respuesta a tu pregunta

En primer lugar: lo que haces **ya es encadenar promesas**, incluir resultados de promesas en el bloque .then() de una promesa es encadenar, así que en principio eso es correcto. Ejecutaras cada promesa de forma secuencial cada vez que una resuelva.

Quizá lo que tú quieres hacer es más fácil si se pone con sintaxis de async / await.

Te pongo un ejemplo.

```js
const promesas = [
  Promise.resolve('esta promesa resuelve correctamente'), 
  Promise.reject('esta promesa no resuelve, inmediatamente'), 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'esta promesa rechaza asincronamente'))
];

const handlePromises = async () => {
  const errors  = [];
  
  const p1 = await promesas[0].catch(e => errors.push(e));
  const p2 = await promesas[1].catch(e => errors.push(e) && `error: ${e}`);
  const p3 = await promesas[2].catch(e => errors.push(e) && `error: ${e}`);
  
  if(errors.length) console.log(errors)
  
  return [p1, p2, p3]
}

handlePromises().then(r => console.log(r))
```

### Una alternativa

Hablas de que quieres gestionar las tres promesas con un único then/catch

Realmente no te hace falta en absoluto encadenar las promesas. En este caso en particular, de hecho, las promesas que defines no dependen unas de las otras.

Para esto (repito, cuando tus promesas no dependan las unas de las otras) podrias usar [Promise.allSetled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), que ejecuta todas las promesas que tienes y te devolverá un Array con su resultado.

Podrías, después evaluar si alguna de las promesas ha sido rechazada y transformar los códigos de error como tú estimes oportuno.

```js
const promesas = [
  Promise.resolve('esta promesa resuelve correctamente'), 
  Promise.reject('esta promesa no resuelve, inmediatamente'), 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'esta promesa rechaza asincronamente'))
];

Promise.allSettled(promesas).then(result => {
  const succeededPromises = result.filter(({status}) => status === 'fulfilled') 
  const erroredPromises = result.filter(({status}) => status === 'rejected')
  console.log({erroredPromises, succeededPromises});
})
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y a entender un poco mejor cómo trabajar con múltiples promesas en paralelo y en secuencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme